# Disabling a button for a day

Tags: flutter, date, dart, time

I want to disable a button for the day it was clicked. For example; I have a homepage, user clicks a button and go to another page. Does do something on second page and return to homepage. After that user can't click this button again for today.
How can i create this logic in flutter?
I found 'timer_builder' package on pub.dev but i couldn't implement this logic.

Comment: Why dont you just handle it on the server side? and you can just fetch a bool value from your server and enable or disable accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping the button with an [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html).

```
bool _shouldIgnore = false;

IgnorePointer(
   ignoring: _shouldIgnore,
   child: [YOURBUTTON],
),
```

And to switch the button on and off time-controlled, I would recommend it to you. Here I leave the button locked for exactly 24 hours after an action.
You need [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) for saving the data locally.

When the action is done on the second page:

```
_lockButton() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  var _date = DateTime.now();
  await prefs.setString('lastPressed', _date.toString);
}
```

On the firstpage:

```
//InitState is called when the page is built.
void initState() async{ 
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  //DateTime.parse because you can only save Strings locally.
  // .add Adds 12h to the date when the button was last pressed.
  var _date= DateTime.parse(prefs.getString('lastPressed')).add(Duration(hours: 12));

  if(_date.isBefore(DateTime.now()){
   _shoudlIgnore = false;
  }
  else {_shoudlIgnore = true;}
}
```

Attention you have to initialize the variable `_shouldIgnore` before the InitState.

Comment: If that helped, mark the answer as solved and give it an upvote

Comment: Yes, it's definitely what i was looking for. i appreciative for your help